# Symfony 5 Bundle namespace autoload failed

Tags: symfony, composer-php, bundle, autoload, psr-4

I create a bundle like this

```
<?php

namespace CDC\Basement\Bundle\UtilBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class CDCUtilBundle extends Bundle {}
```

and add composer.json file on root directory of my bundle folder, and put this in autoload

```
"psr-4": { "CDC\\Basement\\Bundle\\UtilBundle\\": "src/" },
```

the main class located in /src folder.

After I run `composer dump-autoload` command, but I get this error:
**Attempted to load class "CDCUtilBundle" from namespace "CDC\Basement\Bundle\UtilBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?**

If I understood correctly after command run, the new namespace should be added in **autoload_psr4.php** and **autoload_static.php** (vendor/composer/) , also in main **composer.json** too like other bundles https://prnt.sc/r9rwss.

What did I do wrong ? Maybe I forgot add somewhere configs or I need to run other commands too ?

Comment: What a file name of your bundle class?

Comment: also typos are a lovely source of errors.

Comment: I added your code to an existing S5 project and it all worked as expected.  "add composer.json file on root directory of my bundle folder" Does this mean you have your bundle packaged as a composer package and you installed it using composer require?  I suspect your dump-autoload is not picking up your modified composer.json.

Comment: Vladimir Tarkhanov, the file name is **CDCUtilBundle.php**

Comment: @Cerad , no, I don`t use **composer require**, I create bundle files manually.

Comment: Is your compser.json with the CDC psr4 entry in the same directory from which you run "composer dump-autoload"?

Comment: @Cerad, no its located in bundle root dir, I run command from project root

Comment: So how is composer supposed to detect the existence of your bundle's composer.json file?  Especially since it's doubtful that you have your bundle listed as a requirement in your project's composer.json?  Might be best to consult the composer docs and work your way through the process of adding dependencies.

Comment: @Cerad , I use symfony official documentation, but thanks for the advice, maybe composer doc can help a more

Comment: This is not a Symfony issue, it is a composer dependency issue.  If you really wanted to, just add your CDC namespace line to your project's composer.json and it should work fine.